# Why are logging and unit testing not (usually) implemented in a single API?

Tags: design-patterns, logging, architecture

I've been working on a program that uses CasperJS/PhantomJS (headless webkit) and I've been using Casper's built-in testing unit testing facilitates.  It uses the standard `assert(test, "message")` pattern.  I thought it would be nice to set the log level for the passing tests to `info` but the two API's are separate and it looks like I will have to duplicate the test logic for both or hack one into the other.

Thinking back to my (limited) experience with JUnit and PHP, I didn't remember any logging options. Google turns up some logging options for JUnit, but looks like it's bolted on.

Is this just CasperJS or is it common to have distinct logging/unit testing API's? If so, is this just a result of differing legacy's or are there architectural/linguistic reasons that having two separate facilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing and logging are somewhat orthogonal concepts.

Unit tests, upon a failure, should provide a clear pointer to what went wrong, and leave it up to you to do a further investigation. They typically should not print anything out when they pass. The framework would just print out a summary of how many passed and how many failed.

Comment: Right, I think the divergence comes down to inline tests vs independent tests.  Whereas (especially in the OO world) I would have a batch of unit tests that create mock data/objects to represent different use cases, logging just reports what's going on.  Casper is a built for testing, so it's operations are closely linked to what a unit tests would cover.